# How can I change the cell colour randomly on hover every 1 second?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying and failing to randomly change the background colour of the specific cell while hovering only (then set the color back to grey afterwards when inactive).

I'm using a randomColor generator which is feeding me the correct RGB format in my setInterval loop within my .hover(), but I can't figure out why its not changing the color. $(this) is having no effect. I'm sure its a scope issue, I just can't seem to get it.

````
$(document).ready(function(){

  var setGridDimensions = function(r, c) {
    var html = '';
    for (var i = 0; i < r; i++) {
      html += '<div class="row">';
      for (var j = 0; j < c; j++) {
        html += '<div class="col"></div>';
      }
      html += '</div>';
    }

    $('#grid').html(html);
  };
  setGridDimensions(5, 5);


  $('.col').on('mouseenter', function(){
    function randomNumber() {
      return Math.floor(Math.random() * 255);
    }

    function randomColor() {
      var color =
      'rgb(' + randomNumber() + ',' + randomNumber() + ',' + randomNumber() + ')';
      return color;
    }

    setInterval(function(){
      console.log('mouseenter');

      $(this).css('background', randomColor());
      console.log(randomColor());
    },1000);

    // $(this).css('background', randomColor());
  }).on('mouseleave', function(){
    console.log('mouseleave');
    $(this).css('background', '#333');
  });
});

```
````

Comment: Have you tried debugging it? Place a breakpoint at $(this) and see what $(this) is actually referencing.

Comment: after `$('.col').on('mouseenter', function(){` try adding something like `var self = $(this); `then replace the "$(this)" part in your set interval function.

Comment: Could you post the part of your html that goes along you JS  or create a JSFIDDLE?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's a scope issue. Like I commented, I would suggested using breakpoints in the console to see for yourself.

The context of setInterval is the window, so when you call $(this) inside that function, "this" is the window (and not the .col like you expected). Another way to call setInterval, that might make it's scope a little more obvious is `window.setInterval`.

You can fix this by doing `var button = $(this)` just before the setInterval and then do `button.css('background', randomColor());`. The whole thing would look like:

```
var button = $(this); // this is new
setInterval(function() {
    console.log('mouseenter');
    button.css('background', randomColor()); // no longer doing $(this)
    console.log(randomColor());
}, 1000);
```

Also, your `.on(mouseleave)` doesn't stop the interval function. Make sure you explicitly end the setInterval.

Comment: That (kinda ) did it, thank you! The only problem now is clearing the interval and reverting the default color back to #333 on mouseleave...